# Remove duplicate values on each string in R

Tags: r, duplicates

i have a dataframe with two columns:

```
 VAR1.                     VAR2.

  A.              102 million; 102 million

  B.      0.1 million; 2 million; 0.1 million; 2 million
```

I want to remove duplicate values of VAR2. for each row, obtaining

```
 VAR1.           VAR2.

  A.          102 million

  B.     0.1 million; 2 million
```

How can I do?

thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Using base R, we can split the string on `";"` and `paste` `unique` entries for `VAR2`

```
sapply(strsplit(df$VAR2, ";"), function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse = ";"))
#[1] "102 million"           "0.1 million;2 million"
```

---

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr` we can use `separate_rows` to bring `VAR2` into different rows and then `paste` only `unique` entries per group.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
 separate_rows(VAR2, sep = ";") %>%
 group_by(VAR1) %>%
 summarise(VAR2 = paste(unique(VAR2), collapse = ";"))

#  VAR1  VAR2                 
#  <fct> <chr>                
#1 A     102 million          
#2 B     0.1 million;2 million
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `sub` which seems to work:

```
x <- "0.1 million; 2 million; 0.1 million; 2 million"
gsub("\\b(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?) ([^;]+); (?=.*\\b\\1 \\2\\b)", "", x, perl=TRUE)

[1] "0.1 million; 2 million"
```

The general strategy used here is to match a number, with an optional decimal component, followed by another word, provided that this number-word term appears at least once downstream in the input string.  If it does appear again, then we remove the first terms by replacing with empty string.  Note that the last occurrence of a pair of terms would not be deleted, owing to that the positive lookahead would fail.

Comment: Is there a way to generalize the above to include any repeat pattern, not just that follow the above pattern?