# How to remove duplicated characters from each rows of a column?

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

How can I remove duplicate characters from the strings of a column using R? 
For example, This is my column:

```
df<- data.frame(name = c(A="a,a,b,c,d,d,d",
                            B="a,b,b,b,f",
                            C="d,d,d,d",
                            D="a,a"))
```

And my expected column:

```
df<- data.frame(name = c(A="a,b,c,d",
                            B="a,b,f",
                            C="d",
                            D="a"))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove duplicate values on each string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56324669/remove-duplicate-values-on-each-string-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `tidyverse` we can first add rownames as column, separate comma separated string into `separate_rows`, `group_by` `rowname` and remove `duplicated` values and convert them to comma separated string again using `toString`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  separate_rows(name, sep = ",") %>%
  group_by(rowname) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(name)) %>%
  summarise(name = toString(name)) %>%
  column_to_rownames()

#        name
#A a, b, c, d
#B    a, b, f
#C          d
#D          a
```

Base R approach using `sapply` which is quite same as @tmfmnk

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$name), ","), function(x) toString(unique(x)))
#[1] "a, b, c, d" "a, b, f"    "d"          "a"
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `map` and `strsplit`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   mutate(name = strsplit(as.character(name), ",") %>% 
   map(~toString(unique(.x))))
#        name
#1 a, b, c, d
#2    a, b, f
#3          d
#4          a
```

---

Or in `base R` with regex

```
sub(",$", "", gsub("([a-z],)\\1+", "\\1", paste0(df$name, ",")))
#[1] "a,b,c,d" "a,b,f"   "d"       "a"
```

Answer (score 0):

One `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(name = toString(unique(unlist(strsplit(name, ",")))))

  name      
  <chr>     
1 a, b, c, d
2 a, b, f   
3 d         
4 a
```

The same with `base R`:

```
sapply(df$name, function(x) toString(unique(unlist(strsplit(x, ",")))), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
```